# can't run stipdet in open cv

Tags: linux, opencv

I 'm trying to run some precompiled code (source code is not available) on Ubuntu, which requires openCV to be installed. I installed the latest version of openCV (from the SVN) yesterday, and installed it according to the debian install guide on the openCV website (cmake -> make -> sudo make install) and everything seemed to go fine.

I tried to run stipdet program but this gives me following error.

**bash: ./stipdet: cannot execute binary file**

Please can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does:

```
file $(which stipdet)
```

...say?  I'm guessing it was built for a CPU you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `chmod 755 ./stipdet` to make stipdet executable.

Comment: The issue was with processor. The file was built for x64 system but my linux os was x86(32 bit version). That's why it was giving error.